# What improvements can I make to avoid these If statments?

Tags: java

I have Model Object Car.

```
public class Car
{
  private String colour;
  private String make;
  private String yearOfMake;
}
```

Then a managed bean

```
public Class CarSearchManagedBean
{
  private Car car;

  @EJB
  private CarFacade carFacade;

  public String search()
  {
     this.car =carFacade.find(car);
     .....
  }
}
```

Then I have a JSF facelet with input fields connected to car object by backing bean and a search button linked to search method .There is no Ajax and use can provide values for any property and since there is no auto cleaning can possibly provide values more than one property but search only uses one.

Then before I show `CarFacade` I will show CarDao becasue I think makes more sense here.

```
public class CarDaoImpl implements CarDao
{
  public Car findByColour(Car car){
  //Calls a webservice method
  }
  public Car findByMake(Car car){
  //Calls a webservice method
  }
  public Car findByYearOfMake(Car car){
  //Calls a webservice method
  }

}
```

Now if the CarFacade I have this ugly if statment that I do not know how to avoid.

```
public class CarFacade

{
   @EJB
   CarDao carDao;

   public Car find(final Car car)
   {
      Car aCar ;
      //How can improve the design to avoid this If statment
      if (car.getColour()!=null)
      {
       aCar = carDao.findByColour(car)
      }
      else if (car.getMake()!=null)
      {
        aCar = carDao.findByMake(car);
      }
      else
      {
        aCar =carDao.findByYearOfMake(car);
      }
      return aCar;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look up the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In your specific case, you're probably going to want to do something along these lines (note - I've never worked with ManagedBeans, so I don't know what spanners that throws).

Leave your `Car` class as normal.  Or, well, you may want to provide specific types for assignments, if possible (So make `Colour` an actual class, even if it only contains an actual `String` - just so people can't assign a `Make` value to it...).

Your `CarDAO` should be multiple instances.  Something like:

```
public class CarColorFinderDAOImpl implements CarDAO {

    public Car find(String colorToFind) {
        // search by color here
    }
}
```

Then your `CarFacade` actually transforms to something like this:

```
public class CarFacade {

    private Map<String, CarDAO> finderDAO = new HashMap<String, CarDAO>();

    public Car find(Sring searchValue, String searchColumn) {

       return finderDAO.get(searchColumn).find(searchValue);
    }

    public void registerFinder(String searchColumn, CarDAO finder) {
        finderDAO.put(searchColumn, finder);
    }
}
```

Which you then call (mostly) as normal from your managed bean.
Please not that there are further abstractions available (such as encapsulating `searchValue` and `searchColumn` in some sort of `FinderContract` object).  But this is a quick basic one to get you started.

Comment: Great thanks never thought I will get this answer.I am already using Strong Types for Colour Make etc and have similar abstractions to FinderContract which I did not show to cut down to bare minimum . Thanks again it does look nice.

Comment: @x-zero How does this avoid the if-statements? Wouldn't you still have to check if your car has a colour, make etc to determine what "searchColumn" to use when you call `CarFacade.find`?

Comment: @dogbane Possibly - it depends on how the decision is being made higher up.  This is only the `Model` part of the program; generally, the same pattern can (and potentially should) be applied to the `View` portion as well.  When returning to the webserver, the parameters passed would be similar to `radioButtonGroup.selected.name` and `searchTextBox.value` - no if statements needed (note - been too long since I've done web programming).